# How to make design responsive using HTML5 & CSS3 ?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to Responsive design using CSS3. I am trying to create a design, but it's not completely Fluid design.

## HTML Markup

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">navigation1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">navigation2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">navigation3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">navigation4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS Style

```
    body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 96%; /* Holding outermost DIV: 960 */
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#header {
    width: 95.83333333333333%; /* 920 divided by 960 */
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#navigation {
    width: 91.66666666666667%; /* 880 divided by 960 */
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I am using this formula i.e. target ÷ context = result

It's not a completely Fluid design. When i rezise my browser, i can see a horizontal scroll bar after some time. So, to some extent i can say that it's a Fluid desing, but not completely.

Wrapper width: 960px i.e. for example 96%

Header width: 960 - (10 + 10 + 10 + 10) = 920 i.e. 920/960 = 95.83333333333333%

Navigation width: 920 - (10 + 10 + 10 + 10) = 880 i.e. 880/960 = 91.66666666666667%

Am i doing something wrong here while calculating the width in pixel/percentage ?

I am unable to understand how to decide that what would be width in px which need to convert into % value. Either it will be 920 or something else for Header, if i have given some margin/padding styles for Wrapper.

For example, if total width of main Wrapper is 960px and it has 10px of padding & marging, then Header should be 960 - ((10 * 2) + (10 * 2)) = 920. Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Looking for some help.

Comment: assume i did -1 on this question :) ... check [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) , its much easier and widely used + cross browser! :)

Comment: I know about the bootstrap. But before using any framework, i want to understand the basic concepts.

Comment: Why do you need to specify widths at all? Try taking them all out and see what happens.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there is no need to specify width(either in px or %), only height is good enough if we want to create a fluid layout ?

Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, I’m saying it looks like most of your elements are intended to fill their containers, and that’s the default for block elements.

Comment: @DeveshM are you able to solve the problem?

Comment: No, i have still some confusions. Spending some time to read a lot about responsive designs in order to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

`960 - ((10 * 2) + (10 * 2)) = 920`  **Nope**.

**Why:**

You add main wrapper a width of 960 and padding 10 to all sides. So total size of main wrapper is `960 + 10* 2 (left & right) = 980px`. (it takes 980px of your browser window and has 960 container inside that div)

**But**

There is a property in CSS3 called `box-sizing` you put value of `border-box` your questions result can be expected.

with `#wrapper { box-sizing: border-box }`

`960 - ((10 * 2) + (10 * 2)) = 920` **Correct**

Answer (score 0):

Use margin:0 auto; to get it to move the way you want. It will center each thing inside itself when you resize the window.

You can also do all your padding in one like I posted. It starts at the top and moves clockwise. If you put 10px it will do ten all the way around. If you do 0 10px; it will repeat.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">navigation1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">navigation2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">navigation3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">navigation4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
width: 96%; /* Holding outermost DIV: 960 */
background-color: lightgrey;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#header {
width: 95.83333333333333%; /* 920 divided by 960 */
background-color: lightgreen;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#navigation {
width: 91.66666666666667%; /* 880 divided by 960 */
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: lightyellow;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Okay. But i am still unable to understand that how should i calculate the width in px which need to get converted into % value.

For example, if total width of main Wrapper is 960px and it has 10px of padding & marging, then Header should be 960 - ((10 * 2) + (10 * 2)) = 920. Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: I guess I am not sure why you are wanting px. If you just stipulate your percentage it should fill as the screen increases or decreases in size, thus creating a more responsive screen. If you are using fixed px then you will end up with a set screen size which will look odd on different screens or some will be cut off when resized.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap framework for making your page responsive. Once you will understand Bootstrap then you can made your own css for making pages responsive.